Is there a place to give objects options for shader nodes like you can with the inputs for Geometry Nodes?
Is there a place to give objects options for material nodes like you can with the inputs for Geometry Nodes?
In Shader Nodes some parameters may depend on the object. I may want to give an object a custom property that allows the material to act uniquely to on that object and allow me to set the parameters.
I noticed Object Color can be used this way. Is there a way to make custom values?
